# Special Riemannian metrics on $n$-torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $(T^n, g_0)$ be the flat $n$-torus. For every $c>0$, it is known that a small $C^{\infty}$-perturbation of $g_0$ produces a metric $g$ such that all closed geodesics of length less or equal to $c$

1. are non-degenerated as critical points of the energy functional on the loop space;
2. and have  Morse indices less or equal to $n-1$.

Is it true that for every contractible open set $U\subset T^n$ and $c=\pi$, a small $C^{\infty}$-perturbation of $g_0$ produces a metric $g$ with the two properties above with the additional property that every closed geodesic of length less or equal $\pi$ intersects $U$?

Comment: Could you add a reference for the 'it is known' part? Perhaps someone (more knowledgeable than me, in any case) could explain why the argument could be adapted to what you want to show. As I said, I'm no expert on this, but it reminds me a bit of these arguments that Kei Irie uses. See his paper 'Dense existence of periodic Reeb orbits [...]' and his paper 'Density of minimal hypersurfaces [...]' with Marques and Neves.

Comment: @LeoMoos, thanks for your comment and the reference. Property (1) comes from the infinite-dimensional Sard-Smale theorem. The estimate in Property (2) follows from the Morse Index Theorem for closed geodesics.

Comment: This extra property I want has to do something with the ergodicity of the geodesic flow.